# Creating csv file from pandas dataframe as per the sheet names in file

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a excel file which has multiple sheets(6) in it. I am writing a python script to convert the each individual sheet into a csv file.

My input file looks like this and this is for example sheetname = class5

```
Name   ID

Mark   11
Tom    22
Jane   33
```

like this I have multiple sheets in the excel

I need to convert them in csv file having just 'Name' and class like this:

```
Mark,class5
Tom,class5
Jane,class5
```

This one one sheet like this I have multiple sheets so what I am using is converting every sheet in dataframe like this

```
xls = pd.Excelfile('path_of_file'.xlsx)
df1= pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet2')
df3 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet3')
```

How can I make csv file called 'class5'.csv with output as above and same for every sheet such as class6,7,8?

Comment: You can pass `sheet=None` into `pd.read_excel`, it will gives you a dictionary of dataframe, which you can loop through and export to csv to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, assuming from your question what you want is the contents of each sheet to be saved to a different csv, where the csv has the name column, and another column containing the name of the sheet it came from, without a header.

If that's what you're after, you could do:

```
xls = pd.read_excel('path_of_file',sheet_name = None)
for sheet_name, df in xls.items():
    df['sheet'] = sheet_name
    df[['Name','sheet']].to_csv(f'{sheet_name}.csv', header=False)
```

key point is the sheet_name argument of read_excel. as the commentor on your question states, leave this as None and you will get a dictionary you can iterate through

Comment: You have correctly got my question, however working on what you said above I am not able to generate any csv file to a loaction. The codes run without error but no csv's getting created

Comment: if it's running without error but not actually producing any csvs, all I can think is happening is that either they're getting saved to somewhere other than where you would expect (can't help you there other than to suggest using absolute file paths) OR the loop isn't running over anything for some reason (to check for this, put a print statement inside the loop)

Comment: I have fixed the issue. also index 0,1,3,4,... was coming I did ```index = None``` to make ```[0,Mark,22]``` to ```[Mark,22]``` . Appreciate you insights

Comment: @greg_data hey i'm a little confused on what ```df[['Name','sheet']]``` name and sheet should be. i'm getting an error: ```KeyError: "['Name'] not in index"``` I'm also trying to save all the tabs as separate csv files. can you explain what those values should be pls? i also appreciate your insights!

Comment: `['Name','sheet']` just refers to columns in the dataframe. `KeyError: "['Name'] not in index"` suggests 'Name' is not a column in your dataframe. Replace Name with whatever columns you have in your dataframe, or just remove `['Name','sheet']`  to save the entire dataframe to csv.